# How to get the BI dataset using python?

Tags: python, automation, powerbi, request

I have a BI dataset in my workspace. This data only exists in my dataset. I would like to know if there is any python script so that I can make the request for this dataset. Is there an API?

I'd like this python script to take that data for me and put it in df

Comment: Yes, there's an API, assuming you mean the cloud version. Did you check the Power BI docs? Tried googling `Power BI API` ? One of the first results is the [Power BI REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/) documentation page

Comment: BUT why do you want that API in the first place? The whole point of using Power BI is that you get powerful analytics *and* compute from the service itself, instead of having to download and process the data. You can run Python scripts in Power BI, you can export dashboards in various forms. If you have to download the data though, you'll have to pay a *lot* for egress (outbound bandwidth), the same way you'd pay for every other cloud service. All cloud providers charge for downloads.

Comment: Every time I run the python script, it will bring me the information from that dataset that's in my workspace. But I can't imagine how to perform this request, which python library to use? I'm new to this world, I'm learning

Comment: `take that data for me and put it in df` does that mean you want to print a report? PDF files contain print instructions, they aren't data documents. Power BI Paginated reports already [support rendering reports to PDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/report-builder/export-pdf-file-report-builder) with the styling and layout you've already created. There's no way to do the same in Python with just the data, short of using your own report engine.

Comment: I want to get the data from this set that's in my workspace.
- I want to make their request, treat them, then save in an excel. All this using pyhton. Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you want to retrieve the data at all? Perhaps you should learn how Power BI works first? Every dashboard or report can be rendered to PDF and exported from the UI, and possibly from APIs as well. Users can even [subscribe to reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/end-user-subscribe?tabs=creator) and get them through email

Comment: `Is it possible?` you keep repeating the same thing. That doesn't make it clearer or correct. Crunching data is Power BI's job, not your script's. You can use Python *inside* Power BI for statistics, analysis, whatever but crunching the data or rendering reports is still Power BI's job. Yes, you can download that data, but that will cost a lot and take many times longer than using Power BI properly

Comment: What you're asking is `Can I extract the data from that super-powerful reporting service that can already render nice PDF reports so I can hand-craft the same PDFs locally?` Yes, but why would you? You already pay for Power BI, why not use it?

Comment: I understood. It may not be practical. Thank you pain your help and attention. I will think in another way to do it.

Comment: I need this BI dataset a lot. This data only exists in my workspace because it has been calculated. I need an excel with this data. I've used power automate for this, but it's taking a long time to create a table in excel. Would it be possible for me to make this request with python?

Comment: Push the data to Power BI instead. You don't need the dataset locally, you need the data inside Power BI. Power BI is the equivalent of an OLAP cube, SSAS, QlikView or Tableau. It's where you process the data, not where you pull the data from.

Comment: Revisiting this - here's a use case. What if you want to grab specific data only via python to run an automate and feed that data to a scrolling banner on a website where the website doesn't allow power bi embed so you need to just output specific values from the dataset? The user wants a script that let's you make a POST and CALL data when the data lives there. What's an example of that?